# Web scraping XML with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've been trying to understand the principals of web scraping, with some difficulty. I am trying to write a script using beautifulsoup that scrapes the data for train schedules (found here http://api.bart.gov/api/etd.aspx?cmd=etd&orig=rock&key=MW9S-E7SL-26DU-VV8V) and tells the user when the next train is arriving. I've already gotten the data in with urllib2 and beautiful soup: I can print it out and see it, but I'm having trouble writing an algorithm for extracting that information. Advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use an xml parser like [lxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.3.2)? The api seems to be an xml api. You don't want to web scrape this.

Comment: I tried to, but kept getting an error message (<lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x1007cdd40>) or else (TypeError: cannot parse from 'instancemethod'
). With beautifulsoup I could at least see the data. But maybe there's a better way?

Comment: `<lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x1007cdd40>` is not an error, it's the `lxml.etree`-object which contains the things you want. Look at the [tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-element-class).

Comment: Thanks for answering a stupid question :)

Comment: Hope this post might be useful to somebody regarding this. http://samranga.blogspot.com/2015/08/web-scraping-beginner-python.html It uses beautiful soup python library for web scraping with python and there is a detailed tutorial for a beginner.